# When I get session,there are some errors about Hive and HiveSession

Tags: java, r, hadoop, apache-spark, sparkr

I am using SparkR to do some analyse about finance.When I try to get the session of SparkR,I get the following error.I don't know how to solve the problem,thank u.

> sparkR.session() 17/11/24 19:23:29 ERROR r.RBackendHandler:
>   getOrCreateSparkSession on org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils failed
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method) at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)   at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.handleMethodCall(RBackendHandler.scala:167)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.api.r.RBackendHandler.channelRead0(RBackendHandler.scala:40)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>     at
>
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:287)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>     at
>
> io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>         at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:102)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293)
>     at
>   io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:267)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:336)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1294)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:343)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:911)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:643)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:566)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:480)
>     at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating
>   'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1053)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:130)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$$anonfun$setSparkContextSessionConf$2.apply(SQLUtils.scala:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$$anonfun$setSparkContextSessionConf$2.apply(SQLUtils.scala:70)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)    at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)    at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$.setSparkContextSessionConf(SQLUtils.scala:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$.getOrCreateSparkSession(SQLUtils.scala:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils.getOrCreateSparkSession(SQLUtils.scala)
>     ... 36 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to
>   locate hive jars to connect to metastore. Please set
>   spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars.    at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:302)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:266)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client$lzycompute(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:66)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.client(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply$mcZ$sp(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog$$anonfun$databaseExists$1.apply(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:194)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:97)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.databaseExists(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:93)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:39)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog$lzycompute(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:52)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.catalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:35)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:289)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1050)
>     ... 52 more Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) :
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating
>   'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder':  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1053)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:130)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sessionState$2.apply(SparkSession.scala:130)
>     at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:129)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$$anonfun$setSparkContextSessionConf$2.apply(SQLUtils.scala:71)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.api.r.SQLUtils$$anonfun$setSparkContextSessionConf$2.apply(SQLUtils.scala:70)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.sca

Comment: as per your error log Unable to locate hive jars to connect to metastore. Please set spark.sql.hive.metastore.jars
You need to define the path to your hive jars

Comment: How do you start rspark? What's your `env`? Do you have any Hive-specific env vars defined? Can you please see if `spark-shell` works fine? Just start it and see if there are any errors. I'm hoping that there'll be a few that are supposed to give us more information on the root cause.